# C/C++/C#/Java compilation library for Android

Tags: android, library, java, c++, compiler

I want to develop compiler application in android but i am little bit confuse where to start. I have searched on google but i have not found any good example about compiler app. I want to create an app in which user can write c, c++, java, C# code and run it easily.

I need a library that can compile from these language, for execution on Android.

Illustration:

[image]

Comment: Compiling means transforming source code into executable code. What programming language do you want to transform from? And what OS should the result run on?

Comment: Check the app which is given

Comment: No, you can not force us to check a link. You have to explain everything in your question, that's a rule of this website.

Comment: Ok. I want to create an app in which user can write c, c++, java, C# code and run it https://imgur.com/UI7OW9q

Comment: Run it on Android, right? Please add all of these details to your question.

Comment: You need a library that does the compilation part, right? If you need the UI/execution parts too ask different questions for them.

Comment: Ok. Tell me the library for compilation part

Comment: First edit your question to add all of these details, thanks! :-)

Comment: I have edited the answer